# How to output result of a SUM SQL query in Appcelerator?

Tags: database, sqlite, collections, appcelerator

The query below calculates the sum of the fields ("real") in the collection and correctly shows the results in the console. But how can I populate a text label with the result?

```
var fetchedTranslations = $.translationData;
fetchedTranslations.fetch({
    query: 'SELECT SUM (sum_words) FROM "translationsCollection"'
});
console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(fetchedTranslations)); //result: [{"SUM (sum_words)":42}]
$.wordCounter.text = ; //should show 42
```

**SOLUTION**

When renaming as Larrie suggested and using the .toJSON() method it works

```
var result = fetchedTranslations.toJSON();
$.wordCounter.text =  result[0].sum_total;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT SUM (sum_words) AS sum_total FROM "translationsCollection"
```

Then you can access

```
$.wordCounter.text = fetchedTranslations[0].sum_total;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It changes the key to sum_total but it outputs an undefined is not an object error.

Comment: I needed to use the .toJSON method as well. Didn't know about the AS renaming. thanks